# VS2012 Ultimate Setup and Deployment Disappeared after InstallShield 2012 Installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield, installshield-le

Before I install InstallShield, the Setup and Deployment can be seen in the new project creation window and when I click the Enable InstallShield Limited Edition, it says "Setup project creation failed..." at the bottom so I decided to install the InstallShield 2012 Spring Limited Edition. After I installed it, the Setup and Deployment suddenly disappear from the project creation window including the option Enable InstallShield Limited Edition. Tried restarting my computer, nothing happened. Tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling the same thing happened again.

Comment: same here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, it was never there in the first place.

[Visual Studio setup projects (vdproj) will not ship with future versions of VS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx)

Comment: InstallShield is there but you still need to download it. I'm pretty sure because VS 2012 Ultimate of my classmates have it even before they install the InstallShield. When they install the InstallShield, they can use it now to create an installer. And VB setup project is different from the InstallShield

Comment: What I'm telling you is a fact. You can take it to the bank.  There was a project category called Setup and Deployment and the InstallShield LE hook was there to capture the users of the old setup projects and get them to download and install LE.  But once installed the category goes away and it shows up under IS LE.  But trust me,  the old setup projects were dumped from 2012 and you never had it to begin with.

Comment: I know that the old one is dumped. That's why InstallShield and WiX is now used in 2012 and the reason why I'm asking why the InstallShield in the project creation window disappeared after installing InstallShield LE.

Comment: Nope. I just ask one of my friends to make an installer for me. It's just weird that some of my friends' VS InstallShield is working and some are not.